# defining typedef for a struct for 2 times

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I saw in a code such a thing like:

```
struct listnode{
char data;
struct listnode *nextptr;}

typedef struct listnode LISTNODE;

typedef LISTNODE *listnodeptr;
```

so why did he use typedef for 2 times???

Comment: One for `struct listode` and another for `struct listnode*` ?

Comment: 1) Properly format code with markdown. Read the FAQ. 2) Because this is bad code which `typedef`s a pointer. Which is a strict don't for reasons of readability. 3) Don't use all-uppercase names for anything else than macros or enum-constants. 4) Read a C book and find a better resource for code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

The first typedef declares an alias for the structure itself

```
typedef struct listnode LISTNODE;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The second typedef declares an alias for pointer to object of the structure type.

```
typedef LISTNODE * listnodeptr;
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is matter of style whether to use several typedefs of just one.

All these three declarations could be combined in one declaration

```
typedef struct listnode{
char data;
struct listnode *nextptr;
} LISTNODE, *listnodeptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two `typedef`s here are not repetitive, they alias two **different** types.

- `typedef struct listnode LISTNODE;` creates the type `LISTNODE` which is an alias of `struct listnode`
- `typedef LISTNODE *listnodeptr;` creates the type `listnodeptr` which is an alias of `LISTNODE *`, i.e., `struct listnode *`